# Web Application permissions usage for html objects like Buttons etc

Tags: jsf, primefaces, permissions

What i am confused of is how to appropriately apply permissions(enable or disable) access to a JSF / HTML field of a form for some "logged in my application" user. Lets say i have a page with 2 textboxes and a button. I want only a certain user to change one of the textboxes. The permissions would be read from a database.
Is there a link to some internet content about certain techniques. I tried googling but they all stay in explaining authenticating and permissions per calls not objects on the html page. A link, book or an explanation guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Most components in jsf have a `disabled` attribute so you **can** use that

Comment: maybe you can research about role based permission. Then, you can add in your button rendered="#{p:ifGranted('Certain Role You')}" to check if that logged-in user is assigned to that specific role.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest a EL evaluation as Fritz comments: `disabled = "#{not currentUser.havePermission (component.id)}"`. Where currentUser is a SessionContext bean for fetch user information as name, permission list, password...

Then `boolean havePermission(component.id)` can find if current object ID is allowed by permission list.

For managing a lot of objects, you can use "massAttribute" (Omnifaces library).
http://showcase.omnifaces.org/taghandlers/massAttribute